# Meteor: organising a loop on server side

Tags: meteor

How do I manage to run loops on server side of Meteor?
e.g.
I want to add something to database every 3 seconds.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    setInterval(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function() {
        post.type = types[getRandomInt(0,3)];
        post.message = 'sometext';
        post.timeCreated = new Date().valueOf();
        post.source = sources[getRandomInt(0,1)];

        Posts.insert(post);
        console.log('New post was added.');
    }, 1000));
}
```

but it doesnt make any sense: data generates very fast, without any delay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have something wrong in your understanding of `setInterval`, you could find how it works at [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

As your code, you write `setInterval` in loop, which equals to call `setInterval` for 100 times. So 100 records would be inserted to your collection each time.

I could give you an example of insert record into `Post` per second at two ways.

PS: I prefer to use [Meteor.setTimeout](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_settimeout) and other Meteor methods than `Meteor.bindEnvironment`

```js
// First: only use setInterval
function insertPostsHandler(frequency) {
  var count = 0;
  // Meteor.setInterval would returns a handle
  // which can be used by Meteor.clearInterval to stop it
  var insertHandler = Meteor.setInterval(function() {
    if (count++ < frequency) {
      post.type = types[getRandomInt(0,3)];
      post.message = 'some text';
      post.timeCreated = new Date().valueOf();
      post.source = sources[getRandomInt(0,1)];

      Posts.insert(post);
      console.log('New post was added.');
    } else {
      // stop the timer when count >= frequency
      Meteor.clearInterval(insertHandler);
    }
  }, 1000);  // insert a record nearly per second
}


// Second: use setTimeout
function insertPostsHandler(frequency) {
  Meteor.setTimeout(insertPost, 1000, 0, frequency);
}
// You could also write directly, but I prefer to use a function holding it
// Because the code would be more clearly

// Meteor.setTimeout(insertPost, 1000, 0, frequency);

function insertPost(count, frequency) {
  if (count < frequency) {
    post.type = types[getRandomInt(0,3)];
    post.message = 'some text';
    post.timeCreated = new Date().valueOf();
    post.source = sources[getRandomInt(0,1)];

    Posts.insert(post);
    console.log('New post was added.');

    // call insertPost recursively when count < frequency
    setTimeout(insertPost, 1000, ++count, frequency);
  }
}
```

You could use either one of them to insert post record

I wish it could help :-)

Answer (score 0):

[synced-cron](https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/synced-cron) is also a convenient package for running cron jobs on the server.